# Parse through a JSON file and pick out certain properties

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file containing over 8000 features. An example of one is below:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"uuid":"____","part2":"_____","length":"529","function":"______"},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-360909.60698310119,7600968.922204642,0.0],[-361357.344715965,7600811.951385159,0.0],[-361805.08159795138,7600654.939420643,0.0]]}}
```

I am trying to use python to iterate through the features and print out certain aspects from the properties. At the minute I have the following code which is iterating through the features and printing the 1st feature and its properties 8420 times.

```
import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('file.json')

# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)

# Iterating through the json
# list
for i in data['features']:
    print(data["features"][0]["properties"])
```

How can I amend the above to show the features and properties for each of the 8420 features? I have tried

```
for i in data['features']:
    print(data["features"][i]["properties"])
```

but I get the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a dictionary, not an index.

```
for i in data['features']:
    print(i["properties"])
```

If it was important to you to use an index, use `enumerate` or `range`:

```
for i, d in enumerate(data['features']):
    # data['features'][i] == d
```

```
for i in range(len(data['features'])):
    # data['features'][i] ...
```